# How do I resolve this WIF/WCF exception?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wif

I am trying to implement [How To: Enable WIF for a WCF Web Service Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161104.aspx).  I get all the way to Step 3 - Test Your Solution where I get the following exception:

> No version of the CardSpace service was found to be installed on the machine. Please install CardSpace and retry the operation.

The exception occurs on line 23 of Program.cs in the Client project:

```
Console.WriteLine(client.ComputeResponse("Hello World"));
```

The stack trace:

> Server stack trace:
>      at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceShim.GetCardSpaceImplementationDll()
>      at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceShim.InitializeIfNecessary()
>      at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CardSpaceSelector.GetToken(CardSpacePolicyElement[] policyChain, SecurityTokenSerializer tokenSerializer)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials.GetInfoCardSecurityToken(Boolean requiresInfoCard, CardSpacePolicyElement[] chain, SecurityTokenSerializer tokenSerializer)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.DisplayInitializationUIAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.EndDisplayInitializationUI(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.DisplayInitializationUI(ServiceChannel channel)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.DisplayInitializationUI()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallDisplayUIOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureDisplayUI()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161104.aspx):
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Client.ServiceReference1.IService1.ComputeResponse(String input)
>      at Client.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.ComputeResponse(String input) in c:\Users\currentuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestService\Client\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 53
>      at Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\currentuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestService\Client\Program.cs:line 23

Answer (score 2):

I've spent quite a while with this tutorial trying to reproduce your problem (this was easey) and fix it (this was quite hard) after you commented on my previous answer.

The thing is, Identity and Access extension has a bug and places wrong issuer address in web.config of the service. If you look at comment of ChrisPD from august 13 2013 at [homepage of Identity and Access tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e) you would see this:

> ChrisPD:
>   While continuing to investigate this I noticed that the Identity and Access Tool puts an issuer metadata address into the config file of "`https://localhost/adfs/services/trust/mex`" instead of the correct value of "`http://localhost:15196/wsTrustSTS/mex`" where 15196 is the port number assigned in the tool.  When I substituted this into the service config and ran Add Service Reference, it generated an issuer address of `http://localhost:15196/wsTrustSTS/`.
>   So there seems to be a bug in the Identity and Access tool that it does not insert the correct issuerMetadata address when the LocalSTS is selected.

I did exactly what ChrisPD suggested and I ran into minor problem with certificate chain building because the certificate that Identity and Access tool uses in the example is selfsigned and placed only in LocalMachine\My store. Therefore it is not trusted. I copied it also to LocalMachine\Root store (I used mmc console) and it worked.

EDIT:
my web.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="http://localhost:14060/wsFederationSTS/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="localSTS" />
    <add key="ida:EnforceIssuerValidation" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
            <!--Certificate added by Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio.-->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message>
              <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:14060/wsTrustSTS/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:49768/Service1.svc" />
      </audienceUris>
      <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
      <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"><authority name="LocalSTS"><keys><add thumbprint="9B74CB2F320F7AAFC156E1252270B1DC01EF40D0" /></keys><validIssuers><add name="LocalSTS" /></validIssuers></authority></issuerNameRegistry>-->
      <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="9B74CB2F320F7AAFC156E1252270B1DC01EF40D0" name="LocalSTS" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

and app.config like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <security>
                        <message>
                            <issuer address="http://localhost:14060/wsTrustSTS/" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="http://localhost:14060/wsTrustSTS/">
                                <identity>
                                    <userPrincipalName value="ellework\ppolacko" />
                                </identity>
                            </issuer>
                            <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:14060/wsTrustSTS/mex" />
                            <tokenRequestParameters>
                                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                    <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
                                    <trust:KeySize xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">256</trust:KeySize>
                                    <trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p</trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptWith>
                                    <trust:SignWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1</trust:SignWith>
                                    <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                    <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                            </tokenRequestParameters>
                        </message>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            <ws2007HttpBinding>
                <binding name="http://localhost:14060/wsTrustSTS/">
                    <security>
                        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </ws2007HttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:49768/Service1.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This does not seem to be compatable with the tutorial.  Where would I get the value for `findValue` and why would I need to set `supportInteractive`="false" when the tool is suppose to take care of the WIF emulation for you?

Comment: I changed `<issuerMetadata address... />` in App.config and Web.config to include the port in the address.  I still get the same exception message, so I tried moving the localhost certificate from `Personal` to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I have added exact app.config and web.config from my demo. Also, I did not move localhost certificate, I copied it.

Comment: I think I am going to try something else.  I have everything the same except for the `ws2007HttpBinding` block in App.config (since I am using federated) and it still gives me the error.

Comment: The ws2007HttpBinding is for communication with LocalSTS. It is important. When wcf client is created, it automatically calls STS to get SAML token. Then it calls WCF service with this token included. Try to merge my configs with yours and see if it starts working. But if you want to try another example I would suggest you to look [at Thinktecture IdentityServer v2](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki)